# Should I test that an SSD is working properly the same way I test an HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bad-blocks

I habitually test new or repurposed HDDs with `badblocks -w` before using them, just as a precaution.

Now that I'm starting to use SSDs, I'm not sure if the same test is appropriate.

Is there a more appropriate test to confirm that an SSD is working properly?